# descriptor of the method decorator is returning undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-eslint

it could be a silly question but i am new in typescript and couldnt figure out what is the possible reason>
In the following code i am console log the descriptor of the method decorator but it is giving me undefined what is the possible issue in it.

```
type function logger34(target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){
    console.log(descriptor);
    console.log(propertyName);
    console.log(target);
  
}

class x {
    class2: string = "12";
    constructor() {}
    @logger34
    y() {
        console.log(`the name of the person is }`);
    }
}here
```

The error which i got is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xoHZ.png)

i searched it but didnt got anything

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet has an error that `type` can not be associated with a `function` as demonstrated in the snippet.

Apart from the above error, there is no other error and this is the correct syntax. I think your `tsconfig.json` needs an update as below:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext", // or any other which supports decorator
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

#### Why do we need this update in tsconfig?

1. We need to tell the compiler the right target that supports decorators for the javascript.
2. We need to enable the experimental feature of decorators.

The following is a working snippet based on your snippet. You will be able to the output in `console`. The only change is some formatting and removal of `type` keyword with function declaration.

```
function logger34(
  target: any,
  propertyName: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  console.log('descriptor ', descriptor);
  console.log('propertyName ', propertyName);
  console.log('target ', target);
}

class x {
  class2: string = '12';

  constructor() {}

  @logger34
  y() {
    console.log(`the name of the person is }`);
  }
}

const X = new x();
X.y();
```